# Random scene manager in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

*This may be hard to understand because this is hard to explain*

I have 6 scenes and one 'start' scene.

The start scene will be where my scene manager is.

So I want function where when the player clicks on the the start scene it goes to a random scene (from the 6 scenes) and then it goes to start. Then when you click again it goes to random scene, but this time these random scenes will be between the remaining 5 (excluding the scene the player just went on) and then it goes back to start. Then it goes to a random scene time, this time these random scene will be between the remaining 4. And so one.

*I already know how to go a random scene and back but I don't know how to do the remaining*

Comment: Have a list with scenes, remove a scene when you visited it?

Comment: @ElDuderino How do I do that?

Comment: @AJ123 Are you familiar with the [C# List class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple a simple list in C# to accomplish that

Suppose you are using the [SceneManager.LoadScene()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) with the scene name overload, you can just store the six scene names in a C# list in a controller on your main scene

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add(\name of your scene\);
```

And then on detection of a mouse click you could just do

```
int i = Random.Range(0,list.count-1);
SceneManager.LoadScene(list[i]);
list.RemoveAt(i);
```

this will ensure that no scene will be loaded twice